# Router doesn't allow loopback, can I use MS DNS to internally forward my .com to the local IP of the IIS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, cisco, windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns, iis-8

My websites are all on public IP x.x.x.110

My dev computers wan IP is x.x.x.111

From within the server, I can type my sites .com address into IE and it loads fine. But if I try them on my other computers, it times-out.

I think it may be because the router does not allow loopback (googling yielded that specific router is incapable of loopback).

So, pretty much what the title says. I have a AD/DNS/DHCP server and one IIS server hosting multiple websites under one IP address, all under port 80.

I would prefer to access the sites internally via local resource, but since they are all under the same local IP and Port 80, I can only access one of them when I type say 10.0.1.15, I ended up binding 8080 to one of the other sites just so I can get to it via 10.0.1.15:8080

Is it possible to use my DNS server to forward .com requests to local resource for multiple sites under one local and one public IP?

router: RV042G servers: 2012r2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is called split brain DNS, you inside.domain.local should have a DNS entry on you AD server that points to your private address and your outside.domain.com DNS server should point to a public IP address, your server can't go on the internet without having it's network address translated, [nothing can](http://whatismyipaddress.com/) - so you will need to NAT the server if it is not natted already. For multiple website on different ports, just edit the bindings and set a hostname for each website and then set a DNS name for each website.

So it's not a routing issue after all.

Answer (score 0):

It's called making a hairpin turn at the router, and you're right, it's basically impossible to have a packet exit the router and then reverse direction and go back in.

You can accomplish what you want in DNS with what's known as split-horizon or multi-view DNS: basically, depending upon the source of the query, you return an internal IP answer or an external IP answer.

Microsoft DNS should support this.